# How can I add polygons extracted from MyQL

Tags: leaflet, polygon, leaflet.draw

I can draw a polygon and save it into a MySQL database.
(If someone need to now how, just ask).

I also can send a SELECT request to my database and show the saved polygons.

Here is what my database returns me

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{},
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Polygon",
                "coordinates":[
                    [
                        [6.146185398101807,46.447689601949826],
                        [6.146475076675416,46.44726084421887],
                        [6.1472368240356445,46.44776352535544],
                        [6.1466360092163095,46.447833752497885],
                        [6.146185398101807,46.447689601949826]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"id",
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{},
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Polygon",
                "coordinates":[
                    [
                        [6.146185398101807,46.447689601949826],
                        [6.146475076675416,46.44726084421887],
                        [6.1472368240356445,46.44776352535544],
                        [6.1466360092163095,46.447833752497885],
                        [6.146185398101807,46.447689601949826]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But how can I add a layer with my polygons to my map with the possibility to edit or delete it, as if I draw a new polygon form my Draw Control.

as is it not an event, I can not use this, right?:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;


  FGgpx.addLayer(layer);

  var shape = layer.toGeoJSON()
  var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(shape);

  console.log("Create");
  console.log(shape_for_db);
  // Save to db

    saveGeofences(1,shape_for_db);
});
```

I tried with no result!
But it's like a creation? Isn't?

Here is the code, I use to get the polygon from my database:

```
function getGeofences(devise_id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "maps/sql/getGeofences.php",
    //data: {data:data},
    data: {devise_id:devise_id},
    success: result,
    error: error,
    dataType: "json"
  });

  function error(data)
  {
    console.log("Error getGeofences");
    console.log(data);
  }

  function result(data){
    console.log("Geofences from DB");
    console.log(data);

    // How can I add a layer with the polygons to my map
    //FGgpx.addLayer(data); // This does not works

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++){
  var layer = L.GeoJson.geometryToLayer(data.features[i]);
  layer.addTo(drawnItems);
}

map.addLayer(drawnItems);
```

The for loop loops over the features in your GeoJSON and converts them into layers so the polygons can be displayed on the map. Every feature is added to the drawnItems feature group that allows the layers to be grouped and handled as one, therefore can be added to the map together. This way the state of the map can be set to the state when the polygons were drawn before saving them to the database.

Hope that helps,
Csaba

Comment: A little explanation is always welcome - explain how the code you've posted works, and where the OP can make use of it.